# How to deploy a phaser game to the web or how to export it

Tags: phaser-framework

I am developing a mini game in phaser but I do not understand how to export or upload it to a server, in fact I do not understand very well how phaser works in that aspect.
If someone can help me, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately your question is equivelant to asking, "How do you drive a car?" as there's lots of pre-requisites to the task.

But to point you in the right direction, here is a simple deployment summary:

1. Install an FTP program to communicate with your server. Try FileZilla - free and easy.
2. Browse to your local phaser game files, it should look something like this:
3. Then you will select everything in this folder, and upload them to your server.

That's a high level summary. But deploying Phaser games is quite easy. Good Luck!

[image: files]

Comment: Thanks for your response , I did it by uploading it to heroku as I have it on a git repository, as you said it wasn't that dificult.